# PowerBI Cant Find Column in Source that IS There

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have a PBI file that imports data from a .csv file which is exported out of Oracle OBIEE. I can set up the data source fine and transform columns to match what I want. However, when I replace the source file with the latest version of the export and refresh my data, I am getting an error that a column cant be found.

I have gone into the query editor and the column in question appears to have some sort of special character at the first position in the string. I dont see anything in Excel and even pasting the string from the excel file into notepad doesnt show any special characters. However, PBI seems to think there is a difference between what it shows in the attached image and what is actually in the header row. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: All the other columns seem to have `type ~something~`, could `Int64.Type` without `type` be confusing it? Also, it is better to use a hex editor to see if there are any "unusual" characters.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Thank you for the Hex Tip. There is an invisible feff hex character before that column name. I dont know how it is getting there, perhaps it's how OBIEE writes data to a CSV file. Changing the column type to type text seems to have resolved the issue.

Comment: I might try different `encoding` options in [Csv.Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/csv-document) in your data import.